# Angular router resolver vs ngOnInit fetching

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest, router

Angular router has a resolver api, which allows to fetch route data asynchronously during navigation before route changes. Component can access this data from injected route data.

What is the advantage of using router resolver over fetching the data on component init callback? It seems like more boilerplate to use resolver, so when should I use it?

Answer (score 1):

In the end it totally depends on personal preference.
The resolver helps keeping your component clean because you just get the data from your `ActivatedRoute`.

I've written an article on medium about this you can check it out: https://official-mkl.medium.com/how-to-load-data-inside-a-component-5414f14ef233

**Edit:**
Also you could implement a reroute logic if your fetching fails so the component never gets instantiated if there is no data available.